# How to use abundant math font features in one article in XeLaTeX?

Tags: errors

It sounds like XeLaTex does not have limit to at most 16 alphabets. However when I declared some alphabets and included many fonts(I indeed included *fontspec*), the message "Too many math alphabets..." occurred as usual.

Haven't I use the correct command?

---

Update

Edited title

**My question**:How to use abundant math font features in one article in XeLaTeX?

Comment: Math alphabets are different to 'normal' fonts. We'll need to know a bit more about what you need to help you out (for example, using Unicode math fonts may well help), but the 16 'classical' math fonts limit is there in XeTeX as it is in Knuth's TeX.

Comment: @JosephWright I need abundant math font features in one article.

Comment: I think you could be a little bit more specific about *abundant math font features*.

Comment: @JosephWright The current XeTeX has fixed the bug not allowing more than 16 math families and can use the full 256.

Comment: @egrep only with Unicode math primitives, the traditional math machinery just can’t access higher math families (only `\fam` can access them, but not any other primitive).

Comment: It looks like [Which version of LaTeX permits more than 16 alphabets?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100426/which-version-of-latex-permits-more-than-16-alphabets) covers things, so I'm closing here.